# com token don't work in php

Tags: php, com, xampp

i work with token (COM Object) , in java Script all things is okay . my problem is creating a object from it in php.
this is the code :

```
try { 
    // flag 1
    $verifier = new COM("pkiactivex.Verifier") or die("Couldn't create the COM Component");
   // flag 2 
}
catch(com_exception $e)
{
  //flag 3
}
```

first i should say this code work in another local system in wampp and i have xampp and i don't think it's because of xampp or wampp but i think maybe a module is missing. about code in my system code run until flag 1 and even its don't go to exception and flag 3 it's go no where , even i see a blank page with no error !!
i know it's not a php error and i put the code just for more detail!

Comment: You will *never* come to `flag 3` because you *terminate the script* if the `COM` constructor fails. Just remove (or move) the `die()` part and handle failures in the `catch` block.

Comment: maybe i said wrong !! even i remove or die("Couldn't create the COM Component"); , the code don't go to catch.

Comment: my problem solved by installing wampp !! i'm sure the problem because of configuration of xampp but i don't know what!! i will grateful of any one who list of all module and config that maybe is necessary for my problem.